# How to call function in child functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am working on react project which uses mapbox-gl-js and I have a question. How can I call function from my child component, so it will be executed in my parent component. I need this because my child component has UI for my mapbox map and I need to perform map-related stuff(eg. execute map.flyTo function). I will use mapbox-example-react project to show what I want to do, because it has similar structure as my main complicated project. Tried to use useRef and forwardRef hooks to make it work but had no success.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState, forwardRef } from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import './Map.css';
import TestJs from './Test';
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA';

const Map = () => {
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef();
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(5);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(34);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1.5);

  // Initialize map when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainerRef.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom
    });

    // Add navigation control (the +/- zoom buttons)
    map.current.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'top-right');

    map.current.on('move', () => {
      setLng(map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
      setLat(map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
      setZoom(map.current.getZoom().toFixed(2));
    });

    // Clean up on unmount
    return () => map.current.remove();
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  const buttonref = useRef(test33);
  function test33() {
    map.current.flyTo({
      center: [
        1,
        1,
      ],
      zoom: 16,
      essential: true
    });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='sidebarStyle'>
        <div>
          Longitude: {lng} | Latitude: {lat} | Zoom: {zoom}
          <br />
          <TestJs ref={buttonref} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='map-container' ref={mapContainerRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

This is my child component, where I want to call my function.

```
import React, {forwardRef, useRef} from 'react'

const Test = forwardRef(() => {
    return (
        <button onClick={ref.current.test33}>Button</button>
    )
})

export default Test
```

Link to mapbox example doc: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/
Link to github mapbox github repo with example react-create-app: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-react-examples/tree/master/basic

Comment: A better approach would be using the Context API, where you create global variables and your child components can access them https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: just provide `test33` as a plain old property to your child component. you missunderstood what `useRef` and `forwardRef` are meamt to be used for (which is to allow a parent component to make calls to/into a child component)

Comment: @DavidSalomon disagree - props are always preferable until the app tree gets complicated enough to warrant global state

Comment: Props drilling may be a mess if you're building an app. If it's just one test website. That might be okay

Answer (score -1):

[Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280867/martin) and [azium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225108/azium) were right [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126151/how-to-call-function-in-child-functional-component/70126871#comment123963834_70126151). Using props to call this function worked.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30441794)

Comment: @camille this is comments from the question made into an answer. It's not a thank-you answer in the usual sense. The thanks can be edited out